# Combining two XML elements into one output element with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file with this two elements

```
<ATTRIB_GROUPS><![CDATA[40,41,42,42,5]]></ATTRIB_GROUPS>
<ATTRIB_QUANT><![CDATA[1,1,1,2]]></ATTRIB_QUANT>
```

This is mine XSLT stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
          <html>
              <body>
              <h2>Products</h2>
                    <table border="1">
                          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th style="text-align:left">Name</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">Reference</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">Quantity</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">Size</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">Size Quantity</th>
                            <th style="text-align:left">Price</th>
                          </tr>
                          <xsl:for-each select="products/item">
                          <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="REFERENCE"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIB_GROUPS"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIB_QUANT"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="substring(PRICE, 1, 6)"/></td>
                          </tr>
                          </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
              </body>
          </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the HTML output looks like

```
Name    | Reference | Quantity | Size                                          | Size Quantity           | Price    
Shoe 1  | REF1      | 59       | 36,36.5,37,5,38,38,5,39,40,40,5,41,42,42,5,43 | 2,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7 | 999.99
Shoe 2  | REF2      | 8        | 40,41,42,42,5,43,44,44,5,45,46,47,5           | 1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1     | 899.99
```

And i want to show this data like this HTML table with XSLT stylesheet.

```
 --------------------------------------
 |                                    |
 |                 Size               |
 |                                    |
 --------------------------------------
 |       |        |        |          |
 |40 - 1 | 41 - 1 | 42 - 1 | 42,5 - 2 |
 |       |        |        |          |
 --------------------------------------
```

Any ideas? Please don't blame me. Im new in XSLT

Comment: Well, which XSLT version can you use? Splitting comma separated data is easy in XSLT 2.0 with `tokenize()`. And then explain which output format you want, is that plain text as shown or a HTML or an XSL-FO table? Finally explain the logic behind the approach to combine the items.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm totaly fresh about xslt and im trying to learn this for my purposes. I drawn a html table with two rows and example four cols with second row so yes - html output will be ok. The xml input are dynamicaly created from the database - as You can see this is the little piece of this only with separated attribute name Size and the attribute Quantity. So we have 1 quantity of 40 size etc.  this values are fluid so table sometimes will have one col or sometimes 12 etc. I have edited my question

Comment: See; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299691/delimited-strings-matching-pattern/38306286#38306286